# How to let the textbox drop strings started with an Arabic character (semi each other) as it does in capital and small characters in default language?

Tags: c#, .net, autocomplete, character-encoding

In textbox autocomplete properties when i entered a character like 'm' it dropped all strings start with 'm' or 'M' but when i write a character 'أ' (this is an Arabic character) it dropped only string start with 'أ' , I want when i typed 'أ' or 'ا' or 'إ' or 'آ' it drop all strings start with any character from those not the typed character only , in C# windows application I'm not using ASP.net
Any suggestions????

Comment: i need it so much , any help??

Answer (score 0):

I am quite surprised to see that neither the text box control nor the auto complete string collection has a way to specify what defines string equality for the auto-complete mechanism. The only way I can think of to get the behavior that you want would be to create your own auto-complete mechanism.

I have done this several times in the past, before the functionality was supplied by the framework, and it is not difficult.

Just use an editable ComboBox instead of a TextBox, and handle the TextChanged event to create the autocompletions.

Here is some untried pseudocode of the procedure:

```
bool textChangedProgramatically = false;
List<string> myStrings; // The list of items that can appear in the auto-complete.

private static myComboBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if (textChangedProgramatically)
        return;

    string searchText = myComboBox.Text;

    // Use appropriate culturally-sensative string StartsWith comparisons
    List<string> matchingItems = GetMatchingStrings(searchText, myStrings);

    string firstMatch;
    if (matchingItems.Length > 0)
        firstMatch = matchingItems[0];
    else
        firstMatch = string.Empty;

    myComboBox.Items.Clear;
    myComboBox.Items.AddRange(matchingItems);

    string fulltext = searchText;
    if (firstMatch.Length > fullText.Length)
    {
        fullText = fullText + firstMatch.Substring(fullText.Length);
        textChangeProgramatically = true;
        myComboBox.Text = fullText;
        myComboBox.SelectionStart = searchText.Length;
        myComboBox.SelectionLength = fullText.Length - searchText.Length;
        textChangeProgramatically = false;
    }
}
```

The trick is to get the right matching behavior in GetMatchingStrings. You may want to use string compatibility normalization to get the Arabic characters into non-presentation forms before doing the comparison, but I expect the right SubString overload might handle all of these cases for you.